# Preview and Pre-Production Testnet Configs

Tags: cardano-cli, testnet

I'm trying to setup [Oura](https://github.com/txpipe/oura) with preview and pre-production testnets. Does anyone know what values to use in the config? Here's the data that I've guessed so far based on the cardano-node [config](https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html) files. Missing shelley_known_slot and shelley_known_time on both assuming the rest is correct. Oura config here for context: https://github.com/txpipe/oura/blob/a559934f772a2e012b514e0567cca0c34770451d/book/src/advanced/custom_network.md

cardano-cli doesn't have any way to query a block hash.

Preview

```
[chain]
byron_epoch_length = 86400
byron_slot_length = 20000
byron_known_slot = 0
byron_known_hash = "72593f260b66f26bef4fc50b38a8f24d3d3633ad2e854eaf73039eb9402706f1"
byron_known_time = 1660003200
shelley_epoch_length = 432000
shelley_slot_length = 1
shelley_known_slot = 
shelley_known_hash = "137fcc090936d258c06dedb5ad5b063c33ed5c4a71a0517b6466415ec83c7e14"
shelley_known_time = 
address_hrp = "addr_test2"
```

Pre-production

```
byron_epoch_length = 432000
byron_slot_length = 20000
byron_known_slot = 0
byron_known_hash = "d4b8de7a11d929a323373cbab6c1a9bdc931beffff11db111cf9d57356ee1937"
byron_known_time = 1654041600
shelley_epoch_length = 432000
shelley_slot_length = 1
shelley_known_slot = 
shelley_known_hash = "90c8bae45d3cb34ef25d84171a74f6e8a4a8f4615fbe289d5a1b21eb6896ac0b"
shelley_known_time = 
address_hrp = "addr_test1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-production:

```
[chain]
byron_epoch_length = 432000
byron_slot_length = 20
byron_known_slot = 0
byron_known_hash = "9ad7ff320c9cf74e0f5ee78d22a85ce42bb0a487d0506bf60cfb5a91ea4497d2"
byron_known_time = 1654041600
shelley_epoch_length = 432000
shelley_slot_length = 1
shelley_known_slot = 86400
shelley_known_hash = "c4a1595c5cc7a31eda9e544986fe9387af4e3491afe0ca9a80714f01951bbd5c"
shelley_known_time = 1654041600
address_hrp = "addr_test"
adahandle_policy = ""
```

Preview:

```
[chain]
byron_epoch_length = 432000
byron_slot_length = 20
byron_known_slot = 0
byron_known_hash = ""
byron_known_time = 1660003200
shelley_epoch_length = 432000
shelley_slot_length = 1
shelley_known_slot = 25260
shelley_known_hash = "cac921895ef5f2e85f7e6e6b51b663ab81b3605cd47d6b6d66e8e785e5c65011"
shelley_known_time = 1660003200
address_hrp = "addr_test"
adahandle_policy = ""
```

Src: https://github.com/txpipe/oura/issues/381

Comment: It would be good to highlight the differences or comment on them in your answer.

Comment: All the fields are different from the original post.